# Ударение в слове благословить

Tags: орфоэпия

Почему ударение в слове *благословить* падает на последний слог, тогда как во всех остальных случаях на предпоследний:

срамословить;
суесловить;
буесловить;
прекословить;
родословить и т.п.?

Answer (score 2):

Вот что нашлось в словаре [В. И. Даля](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ml4Z-gYYZSIC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=1Vy094XKER&sig=ACfU3U3f2--hnUFIlaFFNJfriw_l_3Iuiw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGm62Rzs3gAhXwzaYKHQAMDSIQ6AEwBnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false):
***Благосла́вие*** ср. добрая, честная, хорошая слава; ***благосла́вный***, честный, добропорядочный, о ком ходит добрая слава, хорошая молва. ***Благосла́вить*** кого, хвалить, восхвалять, распускать о ком добрую, хорошую славу. ***Благосло́вить*** кого, или что, хвалить, прославлять словами, превозносить. ***Благосло́виться***, быть прославляему, хвалиму.
***Благословля́ть, благослови́ть*** кого, чем, благосло́вить, благосла́вить, восхвалять, возносить, хвалить, величать. *Благословляю Господа за милосердие Его.* | Желать блага, добра, счастия, призывать на кого благоденствие. *Отец благословил сына, отпуская его.* | Наделять добром, одарять любовно. *Бог благословил его здоровьем, богатством; благословите меня поучениями или наставлениями своими; отец благословил дочь скотом и хозяйством.* | Давать согласие, соизволение: разрешать, дозволять. *На такое дело меня родители не благословили. Благословляю сына на женитьбу.*

Думаю, что *благослови́ть* (благословля́ть) по смыслу "вместил" в себя все глаголы,  указанные выше, поэтому в настоящее время (в светской среде) он и используется. (Уже полтора века назад Даль их практически объединил.)

Answer (score 2):

При образовании глаголов от существительных суффикс И является **показателем переходности** в парных вариантах, например: леденеть — леденить, обезлюдеть — обезлюдить.

Также следует отметить, что большинство глаголов, образованных с помощью суффикса И от различных частей речи, являются **переходными**.

Соответственно, в парных вариантах *злослОвить, благослОвить, прекослОвить* (непер.) и *благолсловИть* (пер.) ударение на   суффикс И  падает **в переходном глаголе** ***благолсловИть***.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это слово имеет два значения:

благослов**и**ть  —  ваш вариант использования (от слова *благослове́ние*);
благосл**о**вить  —  воздать благодарность кому-чему-нибудь (устар.).

Answer (score 1):

Различие в ударении может быть связано с другим типом словообразования: данный глагол - совершенного вида (имеет вариант несовершенного вида "благословлять") и переходный (ср. с близким по форме прославить/прославлять),  в то время как сопоставляемые с ним глаголы - несовершенного вида и непереходные.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит ли сделать вывод, что разница в ударении обусловлена:

1. одинаковым количеством слогов у всех слов;
2. различием в смысловом значении первого (положительное) и иных слов (отрицательное);
3. обязательным наличием сопутствующего контекста, к коему в том числе относится и частица "не"
4. перемещением (сползанием) ударения в словах с отрицательным значением вспять на один слог

Наглядным примером является использование указанных выше глаголов в форме императива:

блАгослов**И**
нЕ срамослОв**ь**
нЕ суеслОв**ь**
нЕ буеслОв**ь**
нЕ прекослОв**ь**
нЕ родослОв**ь**

Comment: Вы называете два фактора: фонетический и смысловой. Смысловой фактор отражен в переходности глагола: они явно противопоставлены по этой грамматической категории. Фонетический фактор обеспечивает удобство произношения и может оказывать влияние на ударение (к примеру, ударный слог способен смещаться к центру), но это  фактор не является определяющим, он скорее может рассматриваться как дополнительный.  Также на положительную или отрицательную коннотацию слова ударение  обычно не влияет.

Comment: @Sharon так не ударение влияет на коннотацию, а коннотация на наличие дополнительного фонетического слога "не" и, как следствие, на ударение

Comment: Это непринципиально. Ударение - это устойчивая категория, вряд ли  оно будет  непосредственно реагировать как на лишний слог, так и и на коннотацию.

Comment: @Sharon творЕц чудотвОрец, писЕц баснопИсец и т.п.

Comment: Из словаря: Суффикс ЕЦ  может быть ударным для односложной основы перед ним: ловить - ловец, глупый - глупец, но старый - старец  или безударным в остальных случаях. Здесь ясно обозначена фонетическая зависимость от длины слова, но это же не реакция на длину слова, а обозначение общей тенденции для слов с этим суффиксом. Общая тенденция для всех глаголов на ИТЬ тоже указывается (односложность, ударение на флексии и др.), но у нас же ряд фонетически сходных слов, и в то же время что-то принципиальное разделило их на две группы. Я думаю, что это переходность.

Comment: @Sharon тАкать потакАть, рукА порУка, чЕсть пОчесть

Comment: Ударение различает слова со сходной фонетической формой, но разные по смыслу. Собственно говоря, наше подвижное ударение для форм одного и того же слова выполняет ту же функцию.

Comment: @Sharon давнО недАвно

Comment: Думаю, что с помощью ударения различаются  варианты с раздельной и слитной формой написания. НЕДАВНО, нареч. Незадолго до настоящего времени, в недалёком прошлом; с недавнего времени.  Сравнить: не давно, а несколько дней назад.